# Add ListBox to DataTemplate from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to add HubSections dynamically (C# code) - that works.
Then from the same code I want to add ListBoxes to each of 'em - and apparently I have no idea how to do that.

I found several examples like adding:

```
ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = ... }
```

... to HubSection constructor but there is no VisualTree in DataTemplate.

Please, ask for any details if my problem description is too vague - I am a WP8.1 newbie so I could skip some important info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found is to create DataTemplate like this:

```
public class ViewSection : HubSection {
    public ViewSection(View view) {
        string xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'><StackPanel /></DataTemplate>";
        ContentTemplate = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as DataTemplate;
        this.Loaded += ViewSection_Loaded;
    }

    private void ViewSection_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        StackPanel stackPanel = findStackPanelInSubtree(this);
        ...
        < adding stuff to stack panel >
        ...
        this.Loaded -= ViewSection_Loaded;
    }

    private StackPanel findStackPanelInSubtree(FrameworkElement element) {
        if (element != null) {
            if (element.GetType() == typeof(StackPanel)) {
                return element as StackPanel;
            }
            foreach (FrameworkElement child in getChildren(element)*) {
                StackPanel result = findStackPanelInSubtree(child);
                if (result != null) return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private List<FrameworkElement> getChildren(FrameworkElement element)* {
        if (element != null) {
            List<FrameworkElement> result = new List<FrameworkElement>();
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++) {
                result.Add(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is this some kind of cruel joke of Microsoft devs or there is a better way to do this?

* of course this is totally redundant but foreach makes it sooo much nicer to read

Answer (score 1):

Unavailability of the whole children collection looks not really convenient. You may however rewrite your handy `getChildren` method to exhibit [`yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword usage:

```
private List<FrameworkElement> getChildren(FrameworkElement element) {
    if (element != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++) {
            yield return (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement);
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: Yes... I could use some C# for Java developers course.